# how to detect when a jquery mobile Input slider is moved on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've been trying to detect when a jQuery Mobile Input Slider is moved so I can get its value, the problem is the slider's handle is rendered after I apply my script or whatever is happening so I can't detect changes in it.

May someone provide an explanation for why this is, and, if possible, a solution?

Live code: http://liveweave.com/hrrHzP

**My JS and HTML respectively:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider-s').mousedown(function() {
        $(document).mousemove(function() {
            $("#title").css({
                "background-color": "#" + $("#slider-s").attr("value")
            });
        });
    });
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>MobilePage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/theme-classic/theme-classic.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="c">

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
          <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
          <label for="slider-s">Input slider:</label>
          <input type="range" name="slider-s" id="slider-s" min="111111" max="999999" data-highlight="true">          

        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m I'd like to stick the mobile version

Comment: You might like to have a read of this: [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Most of the code you've provided is not relevant to the slider.

Comment: Ok - have you tried listening to the `change` event? Or `slidestop`?

Comment: I tried change, but it doesn't actually(weirdly)  listen to any changes to the input

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle (or equivalent) with jquerymobile?  I tried, but as soon as jquerymobile loads, the slider stops being a slider, whereas it's a nice slider without jquerymobile (browser slider)

Comment: Sure, I'm gonna create it and add it to the question | here it is: http://liveweave.com/hrrHzP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the change event of the slider and event delegation:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 
    $(document).on("change", "#slider-s", function(){
    var col = $(this).val();
    $("#title").css({
        "background-color": "#" + col
    });
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/p9jgm6Ly/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for providing such a neat answer

Answer (score -1):

It's because of event delegation.
Try with something like this

```
$( "html" ).on( "click", "#slider-s", function() {
  console.log('success');
});
```

Further explanation.
http://api.jquery.com/on/
https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/